# What do you call the "action of" striping threads across multiple processors?

Tags: cpu, emulation, threads

A question of curiousity,
I understand **[one thread per core]** or with time slicing, **[many threads one core]** But, is there a way even **through emulation**, even with a performance cost, to...

how to say... "have many processors think they are one processor"****

Its possibly an elementary question, but if you could provide me with even a Keyword to search by so that i can learn more. That would be awesome.

Note: My hypothetical application would be running a process that doesnt require real-time operation, Like a single threaded video encoder, or compression utility.

Comment: I dont think it is possible, not usefully anyway..

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If they "think they are one processor", why aren't they?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think he wants to, somehow, merge 4 processors(cores) into 1 and boost performance on serial applications

Comment: I think you're attempting to describe "parallel processing", which is a major area of research.  Basically either humans or specialized compilers need to "parallelize" the application software so that parts of it can execute on different processors.  A non-trivial task.

Comment: Well, _n_ processors will “think they are one processor” if _n_ – 1 of them are turned off.  I don’t want to be flippant; I want to point out that I don’t understand your question, and I suspect that nobody else here does either.  Can you try to explain it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you are thinking of is [automatic parallelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization). This process happens at a software level, though, in compilers, not at a hardware level. A parallelizing compiler takes single-threaded code and tries to transform it into multithreaded code, which can then run in parallel on multiple processors. I get the impression that this sort of thing is still at a research stage, though, and is not commonly used in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

If there was a way to do this, we'd have processors with fewer cores. The reason we've gone to multi-core processors is that we don't know how to make cores any faster than they already are.

Comment: Actually, if there was a sufficiently general and effective way to do this we'd have processors with far more cores.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: No. If there was any known way to make one super-fast core, that's what we'd have. Its internal details would be totally invisible from the outside.

Comment: The point is that it's easy to make multiple cores, but putting them to use is the problem.  If "parallelizing" a program were simple then massively parallel laptops would be the norm.  But four cores is about the most that a "personal" computer can effectively use.